# async process exited not firing c# from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, delegates, system.diagnostics

I use this to run a process from a controller's action

```
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(utilityPath, String.Format("{0} {1}", inputfilePath, outputfilePath))
            {
                WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
            {
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
                process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
                process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);

                // start the process and start reading the standard and error outputs
                process.Start();

                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                //process.WaitForExit(); //If this is commented out the delegate process_Exited never fires
            }
```

if i don't use `process.WaitForExit();`  for some reason the delegate registered here `process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);` never fires.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handler `process_Exited` never fires because `process` variable and controller are garbage collected before the process ends. If you uncomment `process.WaitForExit()` then current thread will be blocked until the process ends and your controller and `process` variable will not be recognised as garbage and will not be collected.